# touchX and touchY is not defined in P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I started to learn P5.js but I have some problems regarding to touchX and touchY, I am not able to find any related document online.

I copied the javascript code from [this](http://blindedcyclops.neocities.org/draw_bug/index.html) website, its basically will draw a blue line with mouse and red line with touch.

I used the touch simulator from Chrome F12 Development tool, which works well on that website.

I then created a HTML file which uses the [latest P5.js from cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/p5.js), everything works fine except when I use the touch, It says touchX and touchY is error.

Here is the Javascript in `script.js`:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
  background(255);
}

function draw() {
  // draw stuff here
}


function touchMoved(){
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  line(touchX, touchY, ptouchX, ptouchY);
  return false;
}

function touchEnded(){
  stroke(0, 0, 255);
  line(touchX, touchY, ptouchX, ptouchY);
  return false;
}

function mouseDragged(){
  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
}
```

And there is the HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>p5JS Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <style>
        body{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.5/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Draw lines!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the CodePen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woQNNP)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no touchX or touchY in p5.js. Instead you can use mouseX and mouseY as they also give the touch position if there is one(I believe pMouseX and pMouseY work for the previous position too).

However There are touchStarted, touchMoved, and touchEnded functions like the ones you used. If you look at the documentation for these in the Events section [here](https://p5js.org/reference/) you can see examples of mouseX and mouseY being used.